# Can EJB timer invocations overlap for a specified timer according to specification?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, ejb-3.0

If I have an EJB Timer (EJB 3.0 to be precise) defined that runs repeatedly in intervals and a single invocation time is longer than the interval, will the container

- run timeout method concurrently to the first invocation
- or will it wait until until the invocation is finished
- or will the second invocation be dropped
- or anything else will happen?

Is it specified in EJB specification or application server dependant? I'm interested in particular in JBoss 5.1 behaviour.

Best regards,

Przemek

Comment: @BonanzaOne so why is it described in the tutorial for JEE 5? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: You're right I have no idea why I posted that.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that I don't think this is specified.

The long answer is that I was sure this was specified until I looked through the EJB 3.2 spec and the javax.ejb API doc, and I couldn't find anything that said definitively.  The spec is clear that if a single timeout fails that it must retry at least once (which would create a weird scenario where an "old" timeout is retrying after a "new" timeout has succeeded) and that if the container/application is down when a timer should have fired that it needs to fire at least one "catch up", but I couldn't find anything that talked about overlapping timeout methods.

I don't know what JBoss does, but for others that find this answer, I do know that WebSphere Application Server implements timeout callbacks for a single Timer in a "serial" fashion.  That is, only one outstanding timeout can be active for a single Timer, and a subsequent timeout callback will not occur if a previous one is still executing or retrying.  After the delayed/retried timeout completes, the server will fire "catch up" timeouts immediately.  This behavior could be stated more explicitly, but the [Creating timers using the EJB timer service for enterprise beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html) topic in the InfoCenter alludes to this behavior when discussing retries:

> A missed execution is a timeout that must have been attempted, but was
>   not, because the server was unavailable or busy retrying a previously
>   failed timeout.

Comment: That's what I was afraid. I couldn't have found it in spec as well, but the WebSphere behaviour seems reasonable for me. I will check on JBoss manually in a spare time, but I wonder if application servers' providers treat it as a rule or implementations are different.